# selenium webdriver close after clicking the button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I want to click on a button and then go to next page using selenium python. but instead it get close doesnot show the next tab at all

```
import time
from Base_Class import *
class Majestic_Domain:
    def capture_domain():
        web_driver_conn = base_class.web_driver()
        web_driver_conn.get("https://tranco-list.eu/")
        CSV_Download = web_driver_conn.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body/main/div/div/a')
        time.sleep(10)
        CSV_Download.click()
        #web_driver_conn.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", CSV_Download)
Majestic_Domain.capture_domain()
```

This is the code I used

Base class

```
def web_driver():
    driver_conn = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver_conn
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some wait time after the click() action:

```
def capture_domain():
    web_driver_conn = base_class.web_driver()
    web_driver_conn.get("https://tranco-list.eu/")
    CSV_Download = web_driver_conn.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body/main/div/div/a')
    time.sleep(1)
    CSV_Download.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```